# Angular responsive table design without changing html structure

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this HTML&SCSS for my table in my angular application

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr fxLayout.lt-md="column">
      <td>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="button position-button large-form-field">
          <input disabled=true type="number" matInput required>
          <mat-label>POS</mat-label>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
      <td>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="large-form-field">
          <mat-label>Net Price</mat-label>
          <input type="number" name="NettoPrice" matInput required>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div class="custom-button-container" style="display: flex; align-items: flex-end;">
            <button mat-stroked-button class="custom-outline-button">
              19%
            </button>
            <button mat-stroked-button class="custom-outline-button">
              7%
            </button>
            <button mat-stroked-button class="custom-outline-button last-tax-button">
              0%
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="custom-form-field tax-form-field">
              <mat-label>Tax Rate (1 = 100%)</mat-label>
              <input type="number" name="TaxRate" matInput required>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="keyboard-button-container">
        <button mat-stroked-button class="button keyboard-button">
          <mat-icon>keyboard</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td style="display: flex; align-items: flex-end;">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="custom-form-field brutto-form-field">
          <mat-label>Brutto Price</mat-label>
          <input type="number" name="BruttoPrice" matInput required>
        </mat-form-field>
        <div class="custom-button-container button delete-button">
          <button mat-button class="custom-outline-button">
            <mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
.low-confidence-button {
    border: 1px solid orange !important;
    color: orange !important;
  }
.custom-button-container {
    padding-bottom: 22px;
}

.custom-outline-button {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    min-height: 59px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.blue-background {
    background-color: rgb(7, 144, 225) !important;
    color: white !important;
}

.button {
    min-width: 64px;
    min-height: 59px;
    &.keyboard-button {
        margin-left: -4px;
    }
    &.delete-button {
        padding-bottom: 26px;
        margin-right: -7px;
    }
    &.position-button {
        max-width: 64px;
    }
}
.keyboard-button-container {
    padding-bottom: 24px;
}

.custom-form-field {
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 200px;
}

.blue-dot {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(7, 144, 225);
    border-radius: 50%;
}
@media (max-width: 957px) {
    .large-form-field {
        min-width: 263px;
    }
    .custom-outline-button {
        margin-right: 3px;
    }

    .custom-form-field {
        max-width: 198px;
        &.brutto-form-field {
            margin-right: 2px;
        }
        &.tax-form-field {
            margin-top: -4px;
            margin-bottom: -4px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
        }
    }
    .keyboard-button-container {
        max-width: 58px;
    }
    .last-tax-button {
        margin-right: 4px;
    }
}
```

The JS methods from the application are removed so it is reproducible.

I want to use css and angular fx to realign the items on devices smaller than 1200px dynamically.
The first row should be filled by the POS input field while
the second should be filled with with net price.
The third should be filled with the tax rate buttons and the keyboard button.
Depending on if the board button is pressed, the buttons get replaced with the tax rate input. The logic for this already exists.
The last row should be filled with the brutto price input field an the delete button.
So on very small devices (width 390, height 844) it works ([Small Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoYvN.png)). The structure on large devices is fine too ([Large Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4KZc.png)).
The problem is, that the structure doesn't change dynamically when resizing ([Responsive 950 px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxZrw.png) [Responsive 700](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybsGw.png)), which results in not achieving the wanted alignment of the html items described above.

Comment: I'd like to help you can you make two screenshots as to what you have and what you want to achieve

Comment: @MoDGenesis thanks, I added a few screenshots describing the problem

Comment: you need add more css media queries for the different sizes. In your code only have a general, and the devices with size-width >=957px. NOTE: generally it's better use the .css for the smaller size and use css-media queries min-width, you'll have so many media-queries as bereakpoints you have.